# Unchecking a check from an emulated checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'd like to know how to modify this code to handle unchecking from an emulated checkbox.

First, here's the original input html:

```
<input type="radio" name="rf538" id="rf538" class="page_checkbox">
```

And here is the input css for class `page_checkbox`:

```
.page_checkbox {
   display: none;
}
```

After the input html, I have this:

```
<label for="rf538"><span></span>Pleasures</label>
```

Here is my css code for the `span` inside the `label`:

```
.page_checkbox+label span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin: -2px 8px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
```

Finally, here is the css code that creates the checkbox and the check:

```
.page_checkbox:checked+label span:before {
    position: relative;
    left: 3px;
    top: 2px;
    content: '\002714';
    color: #f06000;
    font: 16px/16px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
}
```

You can see that there is a CSS for having a `checked state` but I do not know how to handle for `unchecking the checked span box`. I imagine theres some javascript involved?

Comment: Why are you using a radio button when you want a checkbox? Changing it seems to solve your problem

Comment: yep that solved it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't uncheck a radio button without JavaScript or a reset button, what you seem to be after is a checkbox instead, so change the radio button to a checkbox and it works.

```css
.page_checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.page_checkbox+label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: -2px 8px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.page_checkbox:checked+label span:before {
  position: relative;
  left: 3px;
  top: 2px;
  content: '\002714';
  color: #f06000;
  font: 16px/16px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="rf538" id="rf538" class="page_checkbox">
<label for="rf538"><span></span>Pleasures</label>
```